# Client side C# gives error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, client-side

The following code gives the following error in visual studio 2010 on the client side if statement: ";expected"

```
<table>
<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>

<%  If(Session["InsertUpdateMode"] == "INSERT") { %>
<hr />
<%  }%>

<table>
<tr><td>goodbye</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have done this code in visual basic before with no problems.  As I am using c# for the code behind, the if statement is in c#.  Can anyone provide an answer?  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

C# is case sensitive.

```
<%  if (Session["InsertUpdateMode"] == "INSERT") { %>
```

Side note: The code is not client side, i.e. it's still executed on the server. The term "client side" is used for code that is actually executed in the browser.